# CURL POST in Python

Tags: python, curl, urllib2

I have to do this but instead of using PHP I have to use **Python and Django**, and I'm a little lost.

```
<?php

$receiver_id = '<id de cobrador>';
$secret = '<llave de cobrador>';
$concatenated = "receiver_id=$receiver_id";
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $concatenated , $secret);

$url = 'https://khipu.com/api/1.3/receiverStatus';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array('receiver_id' => $receiver_id, 'hash' => $hash);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

I think it should be with urllib2, but I'm not sure about the other things like (curl_exec, curl_setopt...).

EDIT: I did this

```
def pagar_khipu(request):
    receiver_id = '****';
    secret = '*******';
    concatenated = "receiver_id=%s" % receiver_id;
    hashed = hmac.new(secret, msg=concatenated, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()

    url = 'https://khipu.com/api/1.3/receiverStatus';

    data = urllib.urlencode({'receiver_id': receiver_id, 'hash': hashed})
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)


    return HttpResponse(response)
```

And gives me this error:
**`No exception message supplied`**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need any Django function to achieve this. You can have a look at the "[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)" library in Python and do something like this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests, hmac, hashlib

receiver_id = '<id de cobrador>'
secret = '<llave de cobrador>'
concatenated = "receiver_id=" + receiver_id
hash = hmac.new(secret, concatenated, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
url = 'https://khipu.com/api/1.3/receiverStatus'
data = {
  'receiver_id' : receiver_id,
  'hash' : hash
}
req = requests.post(url, data=data)
print "Status code : " + str(req.status_code)
if req.text:
  print "Contents : " + str(req.text)
```

You can install the requests module by using **pip** :

> pip install requests

Comment: Just to add that requests is not a default library unlike urllib or urllib2. You need to install it, preferred way is by using pip install requests.

Comment: You're right, I'll add this to my post ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of similar questions regarding this topic on this site. Just google for "python request post site:stackoverflow.com".

Additional hint: Instead of using urllib, you might want to consider [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) as a library, which has a much more modern interface.